# \ref gives incorrect figure number in Appendix

Tags: labels

The label of my figure is not the same as what is returned by /ref.  My code:

```
\begin{defi}
Let $X$ be a topological space with $x_0 \ X$. A \emph{loop} at $x_0$
is a continous
function $f:[0,1] \rightarrow X$ such that $f(0) = x_0 =f(1)$. See
Figure \ref{loop}.
\begin{figure}[H] \label{loop}
\centering
\includegraphics{loop}
\caption{A loop at the point $x_0$.}
\end{figure}
\end{defi}
```

The result:
[image: strange inconsistent behavior]

Comment: `\label`has to be after `\caption`